# catkin_make fail : must be invoked in the root of workspace

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, rplidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please... Please help.

I am trying to use rplidar, but I have this error below.........
I checked the tutorial again and again but I really don't know how to fix this..
Please help me.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src

ubuntu@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws/src$ git clone https://github.com/robopeak/rplidar_ros
fatal: destination path 'rplidar_ros' already exists and is not an empty directory.

ubuntu@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws/src$ ls ~/catkin_ws/src
CMakeLists.txt  beginner_tutorials  elp_stereo_camera  rplidar_ros

ubuntu@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws/src$ ls ~/catkin_ws/src/rplidar_ros
CHANGELOG.rst  CMakeLists.txt  LICENSE  README.md  launch  package.xml  rplidar_A1.png  rplidar_A2.png  rviz  scripts  sdk  src

ubuntu@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws/src$ cd ~/catkin_ws

ubuntu@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make rplidarNode
Base path: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src
The specified base path "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws" contains a CMakeLists.txt but "catkin_make" must be invoked in the root of workspace
```

After I input

```
 ls -al /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws
```

I got below!

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws$ ls -al /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws
total 24
drwxrwxr-x  5 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jan 25 15:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jan 25 23:16 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu   98 Jan 24 13:34 .catkin_workspace
lrwxrwxrwx  1 ubuntu ubuntu   49 Jan 25 15:04 CMakeLists.txt -> /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake
drwxrwxr-x  9 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jan 24 17:54 build
drwxrwxr-x  4 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jan 24 17:54 devel
drwxrwxr-x  5 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jan 25 15:39 src
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252980/catkin_make-fail-:-must-be-invoked-in-the-root-of-workspace/) by [sophie.shin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29160/sophie.shin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2017-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> ubuntu@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make rplidarNode
> ```

```
Base path: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src
The specified base path "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws" contains a CMakeLists.txt but "catkin_make" must be invoked in the root of workspace
```

There is probably a `CMakeLists.txt` in `/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws`. There shouldn't be.

Can you add the output of:

```
ls -al /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws
```

to your original question? Use the *edit* button/link for that.

---

Edit:

> You are right! I hace a `CMakeLists.txt` in `/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws` .

I'd use `unlink`:

```
unlink /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/CMakeLists.txt
```

Then try `catkin_make` again.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sophie.shin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29160/sophie.shin/) on 2017-01-25**:
I added output!!

**Comment by [sophie.shin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29160/sophie.shin/) on 2017-01-25**:
You are right! I hace a `CMakeLists.txt` in `/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws` .
Do you think I need to delete this file? can I use mouse right button to remove this file?

**Comment by [sophie.shin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29160/sophie.shin/) on 2017-01-25**:
Thank you so much!! you are my hero!

**Comment by [Ferreira_Robson](https://answers.ros.org/users/65974/ferreira_robson/) on 2020-12-19**:
Thank you Guys !! I had the same problem !
May I ask : I neet to remove the CMakeLists.txt ?

**Comment by [wbadry](https://answers.ros.org/users/45332/wbadry/) on 2021-06-16**:
Amazing. Thank you so much.